# Hard coding tracking numbers into the URL

Tags: api, url, https

I'm interested in the possibility of inserting the tracking number into the URL provided in the actual carrier site. For example, FedEx allows you to track your package straight from their site and the URL looks like this:

```
https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/no-results-found?trknbr=12221221221221212
```

Now if I hard code "12221221221221212" into any tracking number I have in my app, would that work, and would it be legal to do without using their API.

The reason I'm asking this is that in Saudi Arabia, some companies do not provide APIs for their tracking systems.

P.S. If it possible, then I'm planning to redirect the user to the site instead of building it within the application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if all you are doing is replacing the number in the URL with a tracking number using the format that you have tested with (https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/no-results-found?trknbr=). I recommend checking the shipper’s docs to see if they will guarantee this URL format will continue to work. Just because it works now, doesn’t mean that it will continue to.

Comment: I hope it's not a stupid question, but am I allowed to do that (legal)?

Comment: I would double check with the shipper, but I would imagine that this info is meant to be public anyway.